# How and when to save data in the database. If the object that is being edited by the user is deleted from the server

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Example: data is downloaded from the server, saved to the device, then displayed to the user. Next, the user goes to the details screen, edit the object. At this point, this object is deleted from the server by another user. Notification of the change of the base comes, the base on the device is updated. At this point, the object that the user sees is deleted. You will not be able to edit it somehow, update the database with it and send the request to the server will not work. The application crashes

Comment: If you are able to update the base on the device then you should be able to tell the device the object it is editing has been deleted. You could of course never delete the database entry just flag it as deleted. Also you could add a being edited flag to the database and not allow a device to edit/delete an entry if this is set. There are so many ways to do this.

Comment: Show alert about deleting an object or return to the previous screen? As an option?

Comment: Once you have recognised that the object you are editing has been deleted it is up to you how you deal with it.